# hover and white space

Tags: css, hover, removing-whitespace

I was wondering if it was possible to make this blue hover in the drop down list cover 100% of the box so it looks like the gamesworld hover. Is there anyway I can fill that white space so that the blue hover effect reaches the end of the box like the gamesworld?

Here is a GIF of the drop down menu:http://gyazo.com/687add4b44f26bf8c325d45ba61ff6ea

And here is my CSS for the nav bar:

```
/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/

#nav_bar {background-color:#a22b2f;
          padding: 1px;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 10px;
          height: 40px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;}

#nav_bar ul li {display: inline-block;}

#nav_bar ul li a {color: white;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  padding: 10px;}

#nav_bar ul li ul {display: none;}

#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {background: #8c1b1f;
                        padding: 10px;
                        padding-top: 14px;
                        padding-bottom: 14px;}

#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {background: #4485f5;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {display: block;
                         position: absolute;
                         background: #e2e2e2;
                         padding:0px;
                         padding-top: 3px;
                         padding-bottom: 3px;
                         line-height: 1.5em;
                         box-shadow: 0 2px 10px;
                         margin-top:12px;}


#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li {display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {color: black;
                              font-size: 12px;
                              margin-left: -20px;
                              padding: 5px;
                              padding-right:39px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that `a` is an in-line element so it'll take only the space it needs, you should try to give the `background-color` to the parent element or add `display:block;` to the `a` element

Comment: Could I have maybe an example, because I'm unsure on what you mean.

Comment: jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/teb6dhao/1/. In the first example, i'm adding the :hover to the `li` that is a `display:block;` element so the background will fill the whole space (in this case, 200px, width of the parent element) while the same rule in the `a` element (second example) will cover only the space that the text needs because it is a `display:inline;` element.

Comment: So in your case just can just remove `#nav_bar > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {background: #4485f5;}` and add this rule to `#nav_bar > ul > li > ul > li:hover` (i don't know your html so i'm basing my answare by the css)